# How do I enable author pages for the role of 'customer'?

Tags: wordpress

I have a website where a customer can enable a front end 'profile' page. These customers have the role of 'customer' as defined by wooCommerce. However, this user role does not provide enough privilege to enable an author page for that user. How do I add the capability of an author archive?

In an ideal world I'd like to continue to use author.php as the template instead of creating some sort of work around author template.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following code to function.php file will add wp-admin toolbar for all users including customers.

This plugin will help you to add code from dashboard: https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/

```
    /* Allow customers to access wp-admin */
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_prevent_admin_access', '__return_false' );
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_disable_admin_bar', '__return_false' );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I should have been more specific. I have a custom front end author page and would like to use the WordPress template authors.php. However, only users with roles at or above that of contributor can be viewed on the front end. I'd like it so customers/subscribers can also be viewed on the front end.

Comment: I don't see a problem of not using a Role Plugin and say who can access what. Here are two: https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/ & https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-roles-and-capabilities/ What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Alrighty! Figured it out. Thanks, everyone for the answers, however, this is for a front-end author page, not backend access.

```
// remove wooCommerce redirect from authors.php template
remove_action('template_redirect', 'wc_disable_author_archives_for_customers', 10 );
```

Turns out WooCommerce disables author archives for customers. In my case, a customer is also a member and therefore I need to author.php template accessible.